# How to save a model in tensorflow by using c++

Tags: c++, tensorflow, model, save

How to save a model in Tensorflow by using c++? I have searched on google and baidu but not find any solutions for it. I then reading the api document of tensorflow, and the introduce is fewer introduction about C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model saving is implemented in Python only. There is currently no way to save a model using C++ APIs. C++ APIs allow you to load and use the models, not to train or save them.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have basic understanding of tensorflow C++ API and know how to construct a graph using the C++ API. You can make use of the 2 functions :

1. `tensorflow::WriteTextProto()` : your can get `tensorflow::GraphDef` (that represents all the operations you defined e.g. Add, multiply, Mean .... etc ) from `tensorflow::Scope::ToGraphDef()`, save the `tensorflow::GraphDef` to text protobuf file
2. `tensorflow::checkpoint::TensorSliceWriter` saves the current state of parameter matrices to external file (checkpoint), it's little complicated but it works well for me

firstly you'll have to get trained parameter to by calling `tensorflow::Session::Run`, which will return a list of parameter matrices to `output_tensor` (see sample below) :

```
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> output_tensor; 
tensorflow::Session::Run({}, {"name_of_param_mtx_1", "name_of_param_mtx_2",}, {}, &output_tensor);
```

where the `name_of_param_mtx_1` and `name_of_param_mtx_2` above should be the name of your parameter matrices in `tensorflow::Variable`, e.g.

```
auto name_of_param_mtx_1 = tensorflow::ops::Variable (root.WithOpName("name_of_param_mtx_1"), {7, 17}, tensorflow::DT_FLOAT);
```

then you need to prepare following for `tensorflow::checkpoint::TensorSliceWriter`:

- base address of the parameter raw data by calling `tensorflow::Tensor.tensor_data().data()`
- shape of each `tensorflow::Tensor` , by calling `tensorflow::Tensor::dim_size(NUM_DIMENSION)`. For eaxmple a 7x17 2D parameter matrix, NUM_DIMENSION can be 0 and 1, where tensorflow::Tensor::dim_size(0) is 7 and tensorflow::Tensor::dim_size(1) is 17.
- name of this checkpoint, the name must be unique from other checkpoints in one file
- create `tensorflow::TensorSlice` by calling `tensorflow::TensorSlice::ParseOrDie("-:-")`, it seems that the only argument of `tensorflow::TensorSlice::ParseOrDie` will be internally analyzed e.g. `-:-` means taking all items of a matrix. if users only want part of trained parameter matrix e.g. to only take 2nd column of all rows, then the string argument would be likely `-:2` , I haven't figured out such advanced usage of `tensorflow::TensorSlice::ParseOrDie`.

Hope that helps.